# MVC using image path for canvas on page with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, canvas, razor

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width ="320" height="260">
```

`<img src="@Model.img.path"  id="img" >`

I am trying to use MVC model to create "update news" page.
 News has an image and i am using canvas to upload images that because users can edit images with editor based on canvas process. Creating news is Ok.But when updating news, i would like to see image  in my canvas that already created . i took my entity and pass it to the View of "update news"-news includes img path- but i cant figure out how can i use this path to show my image in the canvas element.

Thanks alredy.
Sorry for my english.

Comment: we are missing your code

Comment: edited! please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var img = new Image()
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, 1600, 900);
}
img.src = "@Model.image.path";
```

I just use this simple code. It works.

Answer (score 0):

for drawing image in canvas with javascript , you can use this function:

```
function drawDataURIOnCanvas(strDataURI, canvas) {
    "use strict";
    var img = $("#img");
    img.addEventListener("load", function () {
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    });
}
```

for calling :

```
drawDataURIOnCanvas('@Model.img.path',$("#myCanvas"));
```